# How can I get $(r^{1/x})^x$ to simplify to $r$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

`Simplify` and `FullSimplify` do not simplify this kind of expression: $(r^\frac{1}{x})^x$. Consider

```
FullSimplify[r^2+(r^(2/x))^x+(r^(2/(x+y)))^(x+y)]
```

*Mathematica*'s output is the same as my input, instead of `3 r^2`. Is there a way to simplify $(r^\frac{1}{x})^x$ to $r$?

Comment: **Hint:** It is valid only under certain assumptions for $x,y$ and $r$. Try providing that to `FullSimplify` or `Simplify`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To expand on rm -rf's hint, the variables need to be positive and real in order for the result you wish to see to hold. You can tell Mathematica to do this using the `Assumptions` option:

```
FullSimplify[r^2 + (r^(2/x))^x + (r^(2/(x + y)))^(x + y), 
             Assumptions -> {x > 0, y > 0, r > 0}]
3 r^2
```

To see that this is really needed, consider an example where it is violated:

```
r^2 + (r^(2/x))^x + (r^(2/(x + y)))^(x + y) /. {r -> -1, x -> -1/3, y -> -1}
2 - (-1)^(1/3)
```

which is not equal to `3 r^2`. (Thanks to rm -rf for the improved example).

`PowerExpand` automatically assumes that the variables are real and positive, so you do not need to state it explicitly.

Comment: The example isn't illustrative though... the imaginary term is just due to FP math. Exact quantities will give you $3/100$, which is in fact $3r^2$. Perhaps `{r -> -1, x -> -1/3, y -> -1}` would be better... it gives you $2 - (-1)^{1/3}$, whose value depends on the branch of the cube root.

Comment: @rm -rf Thanks for the improved example. BTW -- I didn't mean to steal your answer -- I was assuming that you didn't want to write it up. If I'm mistaken, please let me know.

Comment: Oh, there is absolutely no problem! Feel free to take such comments and convert it to an answer :) I didn't post it as an answer because I'm quite certain that this is a duplicate (perhaps of several!), but I didn't have the time to search for it. So I just provided a hint to help the OP move forward with their problem for the time being (but it looks like they are AFK).

Answer (score 12):

When I want an expression like this to simplify, I'll use `PowerExpand` after `FullSimplify`

Try this:

```
PowerExpand[r^2+(r^(2/x))^x+(r^(2/(x+y)))^(x+y)]
```

Comment: It should be noted that `PowerExpand` makes the assumptions about the reality and positivity of the variables.